# Dropdown list is not populating in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dropdown, javabeans, selectonemenu

I am working on Managedbeans and JSF. As shown below that my ManagedBean contains all the requirements that are required for the JSF to get the value. I have initialised my dropdown list as below. In selectOneMenu, I have chosen the country as a string where it will store the value selected by the dropdown list and the dropdown list will bring up the list that I declared in the Beans.
Unfortunately, it is not happening like that. Every time dropdown renders it gives me an empty value. I have spent days on it but cannot figure out the exact solution to it. I have cleaned my server, build workspace and also change servers but nothing is working.

** ManagedBean_list **

```
private List<String> listCountry;   
    private String country;
        public void tada(){
        listCountry=Arrays.asList("India", "pakisatan","America");
    }   
    public List<String> getListCountry() {
        return listCountry;
    }
    public void setListCountry(List<String> listCountry) {
        this.listCountry = listCountry;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
```

**JSF**

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{loginBeans.country}">
<f:selectItems value="#{loginBeans.listCountry}"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Your help is appreciated. [Empty dropdown list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJvdu.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJvdu.jpg)

Comment: Please show the full code of the `ManagedBean`.

Comment: To exclude the obvious: please reconfirm that you have properly declared `xmlns:f="..."` in the same XHTML file wherein you're attempting to use the `<f:selectItems>` tag. A bit sane IDE should already have shown a warning line there.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the assistance. Well, the issue is not in the tag libraries or beans. It is in the initialization of the list function. I resolved it by including the list function inside the constructor of managed beans class. so that when the constructor fired up. It also generates the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that on initialization, the list is not being called up. I resolved it by including the list function inside the constructor of managed beans class. so that when the constructor fired up. It also generates the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Which bean annotation are you using? You say "Managedbeans", but the source you posted does not show the entire bean, or does it? Check to make sure you are not mixing old style JSF managed bean annotations with CDI annotations.

Comment: This is unlikely the issue. Whilst indeed inefficient, the default JSF managed bean scope as well as the default CDI managed bean scope are sufficient in order to get the <f:selectItems> to load.

Comment: Yes, you are right, On the internet, we mostly see such examples but in my case, it wasn't working so I called it inside the constructor to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

Either convert your `listCountry` to a

```
    private Map<String, String> listCountry = new HashMap<>();
    listCountry.put("India", "India");
    listCountry.put("Pakistan", "Pakistan");
    listCountry.put("America", "America");
```

or

```
private List<SelectItem> listCountry = new ArrayList<>();
listCountry.add(new SelectItem("India", "India"));
listCountry.add(new SelectItem("Pakistan", "Pakistan"));
listCountry.add(new SelectItem("America","America"));
```

Comment: No its not working in my case.

Comment: Next time, try reproducing the issue yourself. You'd have noticed that the original code of the model is working just fine (provided that the code of the view is correct).